# Get and Set methods for Maps in Erlang

Tags: get, erlang, set, maps, global-variables

I have started to learn Erlang, so I'm a noob in functional programming.

I think that I can't have "global variables" that I could use in different processes of the same module. Therefore, I have thought that I could use maps to store data (counters, status,...) and manage/update it.

My question is: Is there any way to do get/set methods (similar to the methods that we can find in Java, C#,...) to access to maps data without writing them in files? Or is there another way to have these data globally.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just forget OOP.
In this approach, other functional programmers can't understand your code and maintenance is so hard.
If you want to keep data in one process, the best way is learning implementation of the [**Generic Server**](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/gen_server_concepts.html) and use your data instead of state of your **`gen_server`**.
If you want to keep some data and share them to some processes:
In one Erlang node use [**ETS (Erlang Term Storage)**](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html) or [**DETS (Disk Erlang Term Storage)**](http://erlang.org/doc/man/dets.html).
In cluster of nodes use [**Mnesia DB**](http://erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html).

Answer (score 1):

> I think that I can't have "global variables" that I could use in
>   different processes of the same module. Therefore, I have thought that
>   I could use maps to store data (counters, status,...) and
>   manage/update it.

Then the map would have to be assigned to some global inter-process variable, and you are back to the same problem.

> My question is: Is there any way to do get/set methods (similar to the
>   methods that we can find in Java...

To what methods are you referring?

You can use a database, like [mnesia](http://erlang.org/faq/mnesia.html), to store data that different processes can access.